# MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: UPDATE

Tags: soql, c#

```
String queryString = "UPDATE Comments__c " +
                             "SET Comments__c = Comments__c + '" + ssComment + "'" +
                             "FROM ts2__Application__c " +
                             "WHERE ts2__Job__c = '" + ssSearchesId + "' AND  ts2__Client__c = '" + ssContactId + "'";
```

I am on confused why this is not working?

I am looking to update the DB in salesforce as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String queryString = 'SELECT Id FROM ts2__Application__c WHERE ts2__Job__c = ' + ssSearchesId + ' AND ts2__Client__c = ' + ssContactId + ' LIMIT 1';
List <ts2__Application__c> ts2Applications = Database.query(queryString);

if (ts2Applications.size() > 0)
{
    ts2__Application__c ts2Application = ts2Applications[0];
    ts2Application.Comments__c = ssComment;
    update ts2Application;
}
```

SOQL works differently than classic SQL. Please refer to the following guide:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm

> EDIT: Upon noticing the C# tag, here are some links on .net integration with salesforce:
>
> http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET
>
> http://code.google.com/p/salesforce-dotnet

Comment: Will this update in sales force as well though?

Comment: Yes, `update ts2Application;` is the DML statement that will do that. Please read the documentation, you will understand better how all this works.

Comment: well, the question is about c# and this answer is in apex. from c# you would use the update(Sobject [] o) call on the Client object (assuming you're using the SOAP/WSDL api)

Comment: In that case check out these links : http://code.google.com/p/salesforce-dotnet/ & http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE and SET are not viable syntax in SOQL. See this reference from the SOQL documentation:

```
SELECT fieldList  
[TYPEOF typeOfField whenExpression elseExpression END]
FROM objectType
[WHERE conditionExpression]
[WITH [DATA CATEGORY] filteringExpression]
[GROUP BY fieldGroupByList] | [GROUP BY ROLLUP|CUBE (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)]
[HAVING havingConditionExpression]
[ORDER BY fieldOrderByList ASC | DESC ? NULLS FIRST | LAST ?]
[LIMIT ?]
[FOR VIEW] | [FOR REFERENCE
[OFFSET ?]
[UPDATE VIEWSTAT ?]
```

For more information about what is available in SOQL, see the documentation:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/

And here's a good overview about moving from SQL to SOQL: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/From_SQL_to_SOQL

Comment: so whats the right aproach?

Comment: You can't perform actions like setting a object field value within SOQL, it's a pure query. The approach is to use a SELECT to query your objects, then loop through them to set values.